# jQuery Editable ID number

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to jQuery and I am trying to use [editable](http://www.arashkarimzadeh.com/jquery/7-editable-jquery-plugin.html). I want to use the id of the the div tag as the entries are taken from a database and I need the id of each so that when I save the info I can reference it. how can I carry the id number?  This is my code:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(
     function()
     {
          $('div.EditName').editable({
               type:'text',
               id : 'elementid',
           submit:'save',
       cancel:'cancel',
       onSubmit:SaveName
    })
     function SaveName(content,elementid)
     {
          alert(content.current);
          alert(elementid);
     }    
});
```

HTML code:

```
<div style="width:80%" class="EditName" id="Name7268">David Price</div>
```

at this point I just want to display the alert containing the Edited david price and the id number of the div tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

editable's `onSubmit` callback takes the following form (though omitting the arguments, as you did, is valid):

```
function foo(content) { }
```

Within this function, `this` is a jQuery object representing the DOM node in question; you can obtain the ID from that.

editable's options do not include an `id` field. Take a look at [the documentation](http://www.arashkarimzadeh.com/jquery/7-editable-jquery-plugin.html).

Also, you have a syntax error.

---

```
function SaveName(content) {
   alert(content.current);
   alert(this.attr('id'));
}

$(function() { // handy shortcut
   $('div.EditName').editable({
      type:    'text',
      submit:  'save',
      cancel:  'cancel',
      onSubmit: SaveName
   }); // you'd missed out this semicolon
});
```

Comment: So quick to respond.. and perfect answer... resolved my issues.. Thank you very much.. Will award you a point..

Comment: @neojakey: Glad to help. Don't forget to "accept" the answer if it's the one you were after.

Answer (score 0):

I reckon you should check the newer version of Editable at http://www.tectual.com.au/posts/7/jQuery-Editable-Plugin-Best-In-Place-Editor-.html

In this new version there is an Event function **onFreeze** and another method **beforeFreeze**. using these functions you have access to editable input and display element and you can do whatever you want.